# Set colors for custom syntax keywords in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using a syntax file in vim that defines a number of filetype-specific syntax keywords. To color files of this type I've also created a colorscheme file for the share directory that attempts to highlight these syntax keywords, however they don't take effect when I open files of that extension.

My color file does however highlight normal groups such as `Normal`, `Special`, `Comment`, etc. As well, when I attempt to move these highlight commands to my .vimrc file, they still have no effect. However, after the file is loaded in vim, entering the highlight commands manually works as intended.

Is there something special I need to do in order to use syntax keywords defined in the syntax files? Do I maybe need to specify the load ordering of my syntax files & color files in my .vimrc?

EDIT: using `:scriptnames`, I am able to see that my custom colorscheme file loads long before the syntax file, which in fact loads dead last. However, my .vimrc file specifies the `colorscheme CustomPersonal` as the last line, far after `syntax on`.

Comment: Oh nice, that did the trick. I ended up creating the `~/.vim/after/syntax/<filetype>.vim` file, as you suggested, but in it is only a single line for `colorscheme CustomPersonal` If you submit this as an answer I'll mark it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.vimrc` will be run when you first start Vim; the syntax file won't be applied until the file loads, and it sounds like it's overriding your settings.

Instead you could put your custom color scheme in `~/.vim/after/syntax/<filetype>.vim` instead of `CustomPersonal.vim` (or at least call it from there).

Another alternative would be to add an `autocmd` to your `.vimrc` to source `CustomPersonal.vim` in response to a suitable event.

Comment: Marked as answer. Thanks! Out of curiosity though, what's that about autocmd and events?

Comment: See `:h :au`. This can be useful for reapplying settings if they get overridden elsewhere and you're not sure where (e.g. you could add an autocmd to change some setting each time you enter a window). But that's even more clunky!

Answer (score 4):

Vim has a built-in mechanism for overriding syntax groups, so if you do everything right (even in your `~/.vimrc`), this should work. The solution suggested by @MatthewStrawbridge might work, but feels wrong, because colorschemes are *global* in Vim, and therefore shouldn't be specified in an `ftplugin`.

Here's how the overriding works:

Most *filetypes* (like `python`) in Vim come with a syntax that defines highlight groups (see them via `:highlight`). These particular groups (e.g. `pythonFunction`) are then *linked* to a set of default groups (`:help highlight-groups`, e.g. `Identifier`). A *colorscheme* then provides combinations of foreground / background color and/or formatting like bold and italic (separately for terminals, color terminals, and/or GVIM) for the default groups.

highlight group → default group → color + style
`pythonFunction` → `Identifier` → `term=underline ctermfg=3 guifg=DarkCyan`

So, for a set of beautifully matching colors that please your personal taste, you choose a colorscheme. In order to tweak some particular associations, you can change the linking of highlight group to default group, e.g.:

```
:hi link pythonFunction Special
```

This can already be done in `~/.vimrc`. As long as the syntax script correctly uses `:hi def link`, the original link established by you will be kept; the `def[ault]` parameter ensures that the link will only be created if no link exists yet.