# How to understand mapping of vim control statements to python keywords?

Tags: python, vim

How can you explicitly pinpoint a keyword in python, like `import` to always be a specific color?

Answer (score 2):

Usually putting

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable
```

at the top of your .vimrc is enough for most languages (definitely Python) and their common keywords. If you want to set any custom keywords to be highlighted by yourself, or set your own custom colors to them, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30023309/8980763), should be enough to point you to the right direction.