# How can I change the String colors inside vim

Tags: vim

I installed a solarised dark theme in my iterm2 zsh and everything looks fine. But when I open vim, for some reason, the contrast on the strings aren't really good and it's really hard to read strings.

I tried setting `set background=dark` but nothing worked.
Here's a screenshot of how it looks like
[image]

How do I change the dark blue color of the string so that it's more readable ?

BTW, I checked out highlights in vim and for Strings, I got this
`xxx term=underline ctermfg=13 guifg=#ffa0a0`, but `#ffa0a0` is the color of light red which I could work with.

Comment: Better suited for [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong since I am not using solarized myself but the colors all seem off so you might want to have a look at [Incorrect colors with vim in iTerm2 using Solarized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278267/incorrect-colors-with-vim-in-iterm2-using-solarized)

Here you can find a great [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30023309/6843322) on how overrinding works in vim

That said, your override may have failed because you did not have the correct highlight-group. You could try (see :help highlight)

```
    :so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim
```

this should show you the currently active highlight-groups and the links between them. There you might find the hightlight-group that has the dark blue color you mentioned. If so you can change it (or the dependent hightlight-group for a specific FileType).

```
:hi <hightlight-group-name> ctermfg=<color> guifg=<color>
```